# Django not rendring correct image path

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have images inside my app media folder but django is not rendering the correct image path.
Here is what I have in my setting -

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static'),]
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR
MEDIA_URL = '/'
```

in my html -

```
<img style="" class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="{{object.cover_image.url}}" alt="">
```

its showing image src

```
src="/accounts/media/images/RAJASTHAN/SIKAR/332001/panshar8688/cover_image/1145452615/1145452615.jpg"
```

which looks correct but when I go in admin panel and click on the image url it shows me error-

```
"c:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\My_Django_Stuff\scratchcommerce10\media\images\RAJASTHAN\SIKAR\332001\Deepkha2623\cover_image\2187831623\2187831623.png" does not exist
```

and the path is incorrect because media is inside accounts, the correct path is

```
c:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\My_Django_Stuff\scratchcommerce10\accounts\media\images\RAJASTHAN\SIKAR\332001\Deepkha2623\cover_image\2187831623\2187831623.png
```

Images is saving in correct directory but not rending correct path, I am unable to figure out this problem, please answer if you can.

Comment: change MEDIA_URL = '/' to MEDIA_URL = '/account/'

Comment: actually it changed the url to -  http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/accounts/media/images/RAJASTHAN/SIKAR/332001/panshar8688/cover_image/1145452615/1145452615.jpg but the path is still same !!

Comment: after changing MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'accounts'), its working but all other images in different apps are gone !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In urls.py of that app add this to url pattern -

```
+ static(MEDIA_URL, document_root=os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT,'accounts'))
```